# Apply lineBreakMode on a sub portion (2 lines) of my UILabel (4 lines)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In short: how to apply a lineBreakMode on a sub portion (say 2 lines) of a UILabel (say 4 lines).

In long:

[Click here to see a screenshot of the App Store in iOS7.](http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/9436/iuha.jpg)

I have a UILabel of 4 lines (in red). I assume this is a UILabel on the screenshot because they are all centered vertically in every UITableViewCells.

This UILabel is composed of a substring that's is truncated on 2 lines max (in blue).

Just spent one entire day on this question and I didn't even found a beginning of solution. If somebody can help...

Here is another example. This is a UILabel:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|                                          |
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  |
|adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh    |
|euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna |
|aliquam erat volutpat.                    |
|Line 2                                    |
|Line 3                                    |
|                                          |
+------------------------------------------|
```

I want it to be displayed in this form (with the first sentence truncated in two lines):

```
+------------------------------------------+
|                                          |
|                                          |
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  |
|adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh... |
|Line 2                                    |
|Line 3                                    |
|                                          |
|                                          |
+------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: The solution [How do I truncate a string within a string in a UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906431/how-do-i-truncate-a-string-within-a-string-in-a-uilabel) does not work with a multiline UILabel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own UITableViewCell, add the views you want to it, and add it to the table. Check this:

[Customizing UITableViewCells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18)

As you said, what you are trying to achieve seems quite complicated, at least not possible without CoreText (and not sure if possible with it).

Basically, when configuring a UILabel, you can choose two properties, the lineBreakMode, that tells you how the lines are truncated, and the number of lines, but for the whole label.

Comment: Thanks. May be I was not clear enough. I know how to use UITableView, the question is:

How to, inside a single UILabel of 3 lines, properly truncate only the first 2 lines. I begin to think it's impossible without an 'advanced' use of CoreText.